# ModuleNotFoundError for spyder-kernels module installed via pip

Tags: python, spyder, jupyter-kernel

I am attempting to use conda to install spyder-kernels and instantiate a kernel on a remote server as per the instructions here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html

When I run the command `python -m spyder_kernels.console` I get an error:

```
/home/selah/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'spyder-kernels.console' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder-kernels')
```

However, I know that earlier today this command worked fine.

Any ideas about what is going on and how I might fix it?

Version info:

```
[selah@lothal ~]$ conda --version
conda 4.6.2
[selah@lothal ~]$ conda list | grep spyder-kernels
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py36_0  
[selah@lothal ~]$ find -name '*spyder-kernels*'
./anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-kernels-0.3.0-py36_0
./anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-kernels-0.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
./anaconda3/conda-meta/spyder-kernels-0.3.0-py36_0.json
```

Comment: Are you sure `python` refers to your `conda` Python installation? Try `which python` on the command line. Perhaps your path or environment has changed.

Comment: @mfitzp from Version Info it looks like it has spyder-kernels exist in primary python installation so if as OP executed python should point it a primary python env and not  any other ENV

Answer (score 2):

Given your comment:

```
"However, I know that earlier today this command worked fine."
```

You may have a conda virtual environment set up which has become deactivated. Try this to see all your available `conda` environments:

```
conda env list
```

If there are any, you can do:

```
conda list -n whicheverenvyouchoose
```

to see if a given one has `spyder_kernels` installed.

If and when you find it, simply do:

```
conda activate whicheverenvyouchoose
```

If you somehow *don't* have any, first, create a conda virtual environment for your work with the following:

```
conda create -n whateveryoudcalltheenv python=x.y anaconda
```

where `x.y` is your preferred version of python.

then do:

```
.  activate whateveryoudcalltheenv
```

Now, go ahead and install your packages via:

```
conda install -n whateveryoudcalltheenv stuff
```

At that point, you should be good to go.

When you're done with working in that environment, just:

```
source deactivate
```

No need to name it.